# Android "O" returns "O" for version

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

In all previous Android versions `Build.VERSION.RELEASE` returned String which was actually a number : 7.1.0 , 5.0.1 etc.

Basing on this, I have a simple version controller that compares the numbers and can tell me is devices' OS was upgraded or downgraded. Android "O" beta version surprisingly returns "O" letter for  `Build.VERSION.RELEASE` which, of course, causes an exception. 
Is this a dead end or there is some method that will return 8.0.0 in case of Android "O"?

`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` returns 25.

`Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL` returns huge build number.

Answer (score 2):

It is not released yet.

There will be a number once the API is stable. We are currently at Preview 2, but have a look at [Program Overview](https://developer.android.com/preview/overview.html)

> Preview 3 (final APIs and official SDK, Play publishing)

I would guess that's when they give it an official version number.